# Perform find over list of values

Tags: filemaker

In Filemaker11.

I have a table, with a field categoryID, and want to Perform Find on these records.

I want to display only the records which have `categoryID` as either 1, 2, 4, 6, 12 or 13.
Perform Find doesn't seem to allow me to set up ORs... or at least I can't see where it does.

How can I do this?

*Note: This table is actually connecting (with read-only permissions) to a table from a MySQL database, so I cannot set up a field which displays the boolean isOneOrTwoOr...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in find mode, go to the 'Record' menu and select new find request. All find requests are ORed together. You can do the same thing in a script by doing the 'new record/request' script step.

Comment: I didn't realise they were ORed together! Fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this (Assuming you using MySql database as you haven't mentioned)

```
Select * from tablename where categoryID in (1,2,4,6,12,13);
```

That's simple MySql query

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not in MySQL, this is in Filemaker (I put it in the tag, but not in the main text, sorry!)... although I *may* be able to use SQL... thanks!